# R plot colors based on another column

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have a big data frame (dat) where I want to plot a value in dependency of the temperature. Furthermore I would like to indicate the different measurement dates with different colors. For that, I already have a column with colour-characters for the different dates. I want to plot like this:

```
plot(x=dat$Temperature,
 y=dat$Values, col=dat$colour_Date)
```

I found, that this does not assign the right colours to the right dates. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Without sight of your data and your output how on earth can we deduce what the "right colours" and "right dates" might be? You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not posting a reproducible dataset.

When I built the dataset, the color assignment worked. I figured out it was due to the class. When I plotted like this, it worked:

```
plot(x=dat$Temperature,y=dat$Values, col=as.character(as.factor(dat$colour_Date)))
```